# Can I prevent a subsequent chained bashed command from running?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I want to prevent a bash command from executing that has been chained using ; from running while the previous command is still running.

e.g. I write and submit `command a; command b`, but while `command a` is running I change my mind and want to prevent `command b` from running.

I cannot use `kill` because the subsequent command is not actually executing. Does bash have a queue of commands that can be manipulated?

To clarify, I am sure it is possible to make a new script or something that would allow me to create a queue, but that is not what this question is about. I specifically want to know if bash can prevent commands after a semicolon from running after I've 'submitted' them.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @magarnicle: What do you mean by *chained* commands? You are just running one statement (command) after the other, which is the normal way programs behave. If you kill the whole script while 'command a'  is executing, this will kill everything. If you just want to kill ' command a'  and have the script to *continue* with 'command b', you have to kill 'command a'.

Comment: If you started it like that, I think you'd probably have to start a new terminal and kill the `bash` session running the two jobs in your initial terminal.

Comment: That would also kill the first command, which I don't want to do.

Comment: @user1934428 I don't want to kill 'command a', I want it to run but prevent 'command b' from running after 'command a' terminates.

Comment: And you want to control this from the outside, when you change your mind **while** comand a is running? You could use a guard `[[ -f skipme ]] || command_b; rm skipme 2>/dev/null`, and if you want command b  to be ignored, do a `touch skipme`.

Comment: That still relies on me having the foresight to do that before I run the commands.  However, it does suggest a solution for some types of command e.g. If the subsequent command relies on a file existing, such as a mv command, just rename that file temporarily and change it back once the command fails.

Answer (score -1):

Consider these two scripts:

**runner.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

while true

do
    next_command=$(head -1 next_commands.list)
    $next_command
    sleep 60 #added to simulate processing time
done
```

**next_commands.list**

```
id
ls
echo hello
```

You can modify the content of the next_commands.list file to create a type of queue of which commands should be executed next.

Comment: Just run `bash next_commands.list` instead. The proper way to read a file is with `while read -r`.

Comment: The question requested an option to modify the list of commands after the script started  if you run the list as you suggested how can the list be changed?